# Android Market: problems with details page

Tags: android, search, google-play

I am trying to open the Android Market in my application's details page.

I am using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=my.app.package"));
startActivity(intent);
```

However, it seems like this does not work in some devices.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, it seems like the Market application filters out applications based on several criteria:
"filtering might also depend on the country and carrier, the presence or absence of a SIM card, and other factors."  http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Probably your application is being filtered out by one of those factors.

One of the best ways to confirm this is to login with your google account in the web market, go to the details page, then try to install the application.

You'll get a message similar to "Your operator is not supported"

Comment: That was it. I was trying to open details of an app without SIM. It appeared on search by Intent.. but not by opening directly details. Weird.....